# Android Original / Default Camera Parameters

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I have an application where i make use of the Camera API to specify my own settings and do some frame processing.

**I need my application to take photos with the same settings the Android original Camera app does**, but apparently I have no way to extract the procedures and intents from it. I have taken a look at the original Android Camera app class file, but it was not helpful, since it makes use of native routines for the parameters part...

**Is there any way that I can obtain the parameters used by the original camera App?** And in which way does it save the images?

I know that i can write to a File stream as suggested in many posts, and i have done so, but how can i actually save the specific information the device puts in the files, such as information on the camera, density, and such ?

Thanks in advance